# URL /phpip was not found on this server

Tags: php

I am trying to install a new web application. To do this on my debian server I followed this procedure:

1) Extract the tarball distribution.

```
tar –xzvf phpip-version.tar.gz
```

2) Rename the directory.

```
mv phpip-version/ phpip/
```

3) Point your web browser to: `http://your-server/phpip/`

When I type this URL into my browser, I have a nice error message:

> Not found The requested URL /phpip was not found on this server

I went to see in the logs:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

And this is what I have:

> file does not exist : /var/www/phpip

In fact in the `var/www` I have only `index.html`.

What should I do?

Here are the contents of  /etc/apache2/sites-available/phpip

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName gestionip.ffdj.defense.gouv.fr
        Redirect        / https://gestionip.ffdj.defense.gouv.fr/
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName gestionip.ffdj.defense.gouv.fr
        ServerAdmin admin-intradef@ffdj.defense.gouv.fr
        DocumentRoot /home/web/phpip

        <Directory /home/web/phpip/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>


        AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

        LogLevel warn

        ServerName gestionip.ffdj.defense.gouv.fr
        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ffdj.defense.gouv.fr.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server-web.key

#        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/ca1.pem

        ErrorLog /home/logs/apache2/error-gestionip.log
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /home/logs/apache2/ssl_access-gestionip.log combined

    </VirtualHost>
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the directory to `/var/www`

```
$ mv phpip-version/ /var/www/phpip/
```

Comment: all my other web applications are in / home / web

Comment: or should I do the change for it points to / home / web / phpip?

Comment: Your other web applications should have a configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`. Either make a new configuration there, or move it to `/var/www`

Comment: I juste have in /etc.apache2/ sites-enabled a configuration for phpip :

Comment: phpip -> ../sites-available/phpip

Comment: edit your question to show your phpip apache configuration

Comment: voici le contenu de /etc/apache2/sites-available/phpip :